# I dont understand how this code can display a string by using just getchar

Tags: c, buffer, getchar

I don't understand how this code can display a string by using just getchar, I know that it has something to do with buffers, but I don't understand it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  puts("Enter text. Include a dot ('.') in a sentence to exit:");
  do {
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
  } while (c != '.');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's `putchar()` that's displaying each character.

Comment: Are you aware what `do-while` does?

Comment: It's not actually displaying a string but a `char`.

Comment: If first character is `'.'` it'll print that and then terminate.  This may not be your intention.

Comment: This is also a good time to learn to use the debugger, so that you can single-step through the code to see what line(s) of code are being executed.

Comment: You may be confused by the buffering. It is probably not outputting the entire "string" until you press <enter> which makes it seem like it is storing the entire string until the end.

Answer (score 3):

Simply reads each character one by one with `getchar` and prints immediately with `putchar`. When encounters a dot (`.`), prints it and then terminates. Hence it doesn't store more than a single character at a time.

[do-while loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do)

> Executes a statement repeatedly, until the value of expression becomes false. The test takes place after each iteration.

---

[getchar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)

> Reads the next character from stdin.
>   Equivalent to `getc(stdin)`.

---

[putchar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar)

> Writes a character ch to stdout. Internally, the character is converted to unsigned char just before being written.
>   Equivalent to `putc(ch, stdout)`.

Comment: I did not saw that you mentioned `putchar` only saw `getchar`. A its ok, a bit short still.

Comment: @Superlokkus I didn't mention it immediately. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: my question how come c variable is able to strore one string if it's only a character

Comment: "...prints immediately with putchar" ---> Perhaps not.  The output is likely _line buffered_ and so no output seen until `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica IMO as far as the program is concerned, any character is printed as soon as it's read.

Comment: @Zodiac the string is line buffered. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the program reads each character at a time from the buffer into `c` and prints immediately. Then overwrites `c` with the next character. No more than a single character is stored at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Code may look like I/O happens immediately, but certainly both `stdin` and `stdout` are buffered by *lines*.

The first `getchar()` likely does not return until a *line* (characters up to and including a `'\n'`) of input happens.  Then the first call gets the first characters, 2nd calls gets the second, etc.

Similar for output. Output is not "printed" until a `'\n'` is sent.

To see output without waiting for a `putchar('\n')`, follow the `putchar()` with `fflush(stdout);`.

To read  one character immediately with `getchar()` takes more work.  No answer for that at this time.